# Are there other versions (art mainly) of the Ravenloft Tarokka Deck available?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, ravenloft

I have the new (Curse of Strahd) Tarokka Deck, but have seen some cards that have really great/vintage art online. I believe that there may have been an older version of the Tarokka Deck for Ravenloft.  I'm wondering how many versions there are, and if they are available, where?

Answer (score 7):

The Tarokka Deck was most recently previously published in **2003** (in the D&D 3e/3.5e era), which is its first stand-alone publishing. The 2003 edition is no longer sold by Wizards of the Coast, and the rare second-hand copy that comes available sells for hundreds of dollars — to illustrate the rarity, at the moment there is [a single copy on RPGGeek's market that is selling for $435](http://rpggeek.com/geekmarket/product/528110).

The [*Forbidden Lore*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/54364/forbidden-lore) boxed set in **1992** (AD&D 2nd edition) also [included a Tarokka deck inside](http://rpggeek.com/image/540610/forbidden-lore). The [PDF edition recently republished at DriveThruRPG](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17475/Forbidden-Lore-2e) doesn't include any conversion of the Tarokka deck to PDF, and only includes the contents of the booklets in the box. However, the original boxed set can be found second-hand today for reasonable prices; one search turned up [two copies at Noble Knight's online storefront](http://www.nobleknight.com/searchresultsnew.asp?search=forbidden%20lore) in decent condition, ranging from $15 to $45.

Comment: Well, crap I should see if mine is still complete :)

Comment: [Apparently, there's an *AD&D 2E* version as well](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Category:Tarokka_Deck_(Item)), but it wasn't standalone.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh-ho! I didn't know about the boxed set. I'll add that.

Comment: Yeah the boxed set is the one I have...