# Has the Dikesha dice set from Forbidden Lore ever been reissued or updated?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dice, ravenloft

The Forbidden Lore boxed set for Ravenloft (AD&D 2nd ed.) included, besides the original, awesome *Tarokka* deck illustrated by Stephen Fabian, a set of fortune-telling / gaming dice as well, which was called [Dikesha](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Dikesha_Dice), and was in use in-game in the Domain of Har'Akir.

([Click here](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1897263/allhailme) to see how the dice look like. Mind you, it's not my photo, as I don't have my own, unfortunately quite badly worn set on me now.)

**Has the Dikesha dice set also been redesigned and/or reissued since the publication of Forbidden Lore** ([just like the Tarokka deck](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86812/are-there-other-versions-art-mainly-of-the-ravenloft-tarokka-deck-available))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, as pdf 'stickers' in the WoTC re-release of Forbidden Lore

As can be seen in a purchaser's comment on [the DM's Guild page for the product](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/17475/Forbidden-Lore-2e?it=1):

> There is also another pdf with the die stickers for the fortune dice on a single page.

### Otherwise, almost certainly not

I say this with some confidence as neither Ebay nor extensive Google searching turns up anything but references to the Forbidden Lore dice. Most persuasively, the DM's Guild writeup makes the following comparison between the  history of fortune telling cards and dice in D&D.

> Card-based fortune-telling had originated in I6: "Ravenloft" (1983), though it was based on standard cards in its first outing. The idea reappeared in the Ravenloft boxed set, but it wasn't given much prominence there. However, RA3: "Touch of Death" (1991) showed the continued interest in card-based fortune-telling, so it finally got a full write-up here.
>
> The dice-based fortune-telling system had less pedigree and has never been as popular.

I think that Shannon Appelcline, the writer of the DM's Guild product description, could not have been so dismissive of fortune-telling dice if Dikesha dice had been later re-designed or re-released. He goes on to talk about the influence of Forbidden Lore on later products, and makes no mention of Dikesha dice there.

I know that these are all arguments from silence, but in my opinion the silence is quite deafening.